# Word wrap in Windows Forms (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, word-wrap

How can I use DrawString to create a word wrap effect in Visual Basic .NET 2005?

Answer (score 5):

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=286

> You can draw text in a rectangle by passing a RectangleF object to the DrawString method. GDI+ will wrap the text to make it fit in the specified rectangle. For example:

```
Dim s As String = "This string will be wrapped in the output rectangle"
Dim rectf As New RectangleF(10, 100, 200, 200)
grf.DrawString(s, myFont, Brushes.Red, rectf)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you provide a rectangle to an overload of the [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984365(VS.71).aspx) method, it will wrap the text within the rectangle.

```
Overloads Public Sub DrawString(String, Font, Brush, RectangleF)
```